# Pip install shap==0.25.2 fails with a weird error

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip

I have a requirement.txt which includes a line for SHAP as
`shap==0.25.2`

This requirement.txt gets copied to a dockerfile and when I run

```
pip install - r requirements.txt
```

It fails with error

```
Files/Directory not found in /tmp/pip-install-<>/shap/pip-egg-info
```

I am able to install `shap==0.25.2` separately.
Even in the dockerfile, it remove the shap from requirement.txt and added it separately as `RUN pip install shap==0.25.2` it works.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

ENV

```
Python version 3.6.4
Docker version 1.18
```